# BB10 Simulator won't start

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am new to BlackBerry development. I am trying to create my BB10 simulator with VMware and I have been facing this issue and couldn't resolve it.

I downloaded the BB10 alpha simulator from the Blackberry site and VMware 5.0.2.

I am attaching the screenshots of my errors.

[image]

[image]'

At first it shows, unable to access "/dev/hd0" and then unable to access /dev/nvram.

My simulator doesn't show up. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to VMware Home, selecting open a virtual machine and then opening the .vmx file within your simulator? I'm using BlackBerry10Simulator-BB10_1_X-1483. When that's done selecting play virtual machine and then just wait until it boots without selecting drives/partitions works for me. I can't say I ever had problems with it so I won't be much more use.

Comment: I have been following the same steps. Also I tried to start the simulator from the installed location also. Both ways ends up here. But I have a doubt, if this could be something bcoz of ram. I have only 2gb ram. Will that be a problem?

Comment: It could be a problem if your settings aren't configured correctly. Go to edit virtual machine settings and reduce the memory to maybe 1gb or less. I still don't know if that will solve your issue though.

Comment: Simulator requirements listed here: http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html, suggests you need 4 GB RAM on the host system. I suspect 2GB is pushing it.  Try on another system.